# OC Store 2.3 Не открывается админка

Tags: docker, opencart

Накатил на докер OpenCart, все настройки нормальные, бд работает, нджинкс все отрабатывает. Проблема в том, что после установки, не могу открыть /admin, пишет просто "Запрашиваемая страница не найдена". Искал решения - не нашел. Только с исправлением прав на папки. Но это же локально, я итак хозяин папок.

Comment: ну а морда работает?

Comment: Да. Проблема до сих пор не решена. 
Выявил вот что: 
Если 
в главном конфиге define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/site/admin/');
в admin/config.php тоже define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/site/admin/');
 то localhost показывает естественно ошибку, но localhost/admin открывает авторизацию. 

nginx: 
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/site/;

Comment: А урлы в конфигах http? Если правильно понял это локалка. Надо перебить секурные на обычные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/thread 
 Ларадок - не для всего подходит, не понятно почему.
Просто собрал чистый **docker-compose.yml**

```html
version: "3.1"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: localhost-mysql
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=anichkv9_mshop
      - MYSQL_USER=vladko
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "8002:3306"

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: localhost-webserver
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  php-fpm:
    build: phpdocker/php-fpm
    container_name: localhost-php-fpm
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - .:/application
      - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini


  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: localhost-phpmyadmin
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

Так-же **nginx.conf**

```html
server {
    listen 80 default;

    client_max_body_size 108M;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

    root /application/public;
    index index.php;

    location /admin {
        index index.php;
    }


    location / { try_files $uri @opencart; }
    location @opencart { rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
}
```

такой-же конфиг из под билда ларадока почему-то не работает.